# Javascript HTML Table Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code to search data in my tables. I'm trying to add a class on the found rows. It works, however once the search input field is empty, it still keeps the class on the cells. Is there any quick way to remove the class once the search field is empty/found is false?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    searchTable($(this).val());
});
```

});

```
function searchTable(inputVal) {
    var table = $('.phonetable');
    table.find('tr').each(function(index, row) {
        var allCells = $(row).find('td');
        if(allCells.length > 0) {
            var found = false;
            allCells.each(function(index, td) {
                var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
                if(regExp.test($(td).text())) {
                    found = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if(found == true) $(row).show() .addClass("searchhighlight");
            else $(row).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the value is empty and if it is remove the value:

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value)
        searchTable();
    else
        $('.phonetable tr td').removeClass("searchhighlight");
});
```

Also look how I traverse the table with `$('.phonetable tr td')`, you can do something similiar in your current code.

Comment: This seems to break hiding the table rows on a search, and just highlights all the table rows

Comment: Hmm, it should probably be `$('.phonetable tr').show().removeClass('searchhiglight');`